# set view transparent but keep buttons etc opaque

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I have two views, one with an `UIImageView` at the back as background. Then I have another view in front of the `ImageView` containing labels, buttons and paths such as circles and rects. I want the second view (the one with buttons etc) to be transparent so that the `ImageView` is fully visible, but keep the buttons, labels and paths opaque. I have set the second view (the one with buttons etc) to alpha 0.5, and the buttons and labels to 1 in IB. And in my code i have set the paths to alpha 1 as well. But when I run it the buttons, labels and paths are also half transparent like the view. How do I only set the view's transparency to alpha 0 and keep everything else alpha 1?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the second view (the one with buttons etc) to be transparent so that the imageview is fully visible

What you need is clearing that view's `backgroundColor`:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

A view's alpha settings applies to its subviews as well, there is no way out of it.

By the way, if your first view only contains an image, you could as well remove it and set that background image as the `backgroundColor` for your second view:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

Comment: But when I added the image that way it was 5 times zoomed in. How do I show the whole pic?

Comment: you mean when using the image as backgroundColor? The only way for this to work is that the image has the same exact size of the view, otherwise it will be replicated.